# set several list columns based on portions of document name seperated by an underscore

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column, incoming-email

If I have a docuent library that has a documents in it using the following format: **Region_Division_Store.pdf**    ...notice the underscores.

I also have three columns named **Region, Division, Store**. These columns are calculated based on the Title Column.

The documents will be added via the email to list capability.

How can i go about setting the column texts by seperating the string at the underscore.

at this time i am able to get the index of the first underscore using    =SEARCH("_",Title,1), but this only gives me the index of the first underscore

Any and all help will definitley be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Title field has **Region_Division_Store** format, here is how it can be done.

Region -- `=LEFT(Title,FIND("_",Title)-1)`

Division--

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(Title,FIND("_",Title,FIND("_",Title)+1)-1),FIND("_",Title)+1)
```

Store--

```
=RIGHT(Title,LEN(Title)-FIND("_",Title,FIND("_",Title)+1))
```